# godan verbs ending in nu besides shinu

Tags: words

Are there any godan verbs ending in nu besides shinu?

Answer (score 1):

The only two ぬ verbs are 死{し}ぬ *"to die"* and 往{い}ぬ・去{い}ぬ *"to go somewhere; to go away"*.  Note that *inu* is obsolete, and is not used in modern Japanese.  This verb thus technically is not *godan*, but rather *yodan*, as it has no *-o* ending in the Classical Japanese conjugation paradigm.

There is a bit more information at [the Japanese Wikipedia's article on the ナ変{へん} or ナ行{ぎょう}変格{へんかく}活用{かつよう} (*na*-row irregular conjugation)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8A%E8%A1%8C%E5%A4%89%E6%A0%BC%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8).

Answer (score 0):

In current Japanese, just 死ぬ{しぬ} according to [this](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13121386318).